# C # - LINQ is mounting SELECT with wrong WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, linq, t-sql, where-clause

Help!
I put the code below in LINQ-TO-SQL. Note that I used only one field in the WHERE clause but LINQ is assembling SELECT with WHERE in multiple fields. I made a PROFILE and captured the assembled SELECT. Can you help me force LINQ to search only in the specified field? I'm using database-first.

My LINQ code:

```
var query = from v in ctx.cliente
                            orderby v.razao_social
                            where v.fantasia.ToLower().Contains(pesquisa) 
                            select new
                            {
                                id_cliente = v.id_cliente,
                                razao = v.razao_social,
                                fantasia = v.fantasia,
                                cnpj = v.cnpj,
                                cidade = v.cidade.cidade1 + "/" + v.cidade.uf1,
                                fone = v.fone1
                            };
```

Now, my result from profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Project1].[id_cliente] AS [id_cliente], 
    [Project1].[razao_social] AS [razao_social], 
    [Project1].[fantasia] AS [fantasia], 
    [Project1].[cnpj] AS [cnpj], 
    [Project1].[endereco] AS [endereco], 
    [Project1].[bairro] AS [bairro], 
    [Project1].[cidade] AS [cidade], 
    [Project1].[uf] AS [uf]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[id_cliente] AS [id_cliente], 
        [Extent1].[cnpj] AS [cnpj], 
        [Extent1].[razao_social] AS [razao_social], 
        [Extent1].[fantasia] AS [fantasia], 
        [Extent1].[endereco] AS [endereco], 
        [Extent1].[bairro] AS [bairro], 
        [Extent2].[cidade] AS [cidade], 
        [Extent3].[uf] AS [uf]
        FROM   [dbo].[cliente] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[cidade] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[id_cidade] = [Extent2].[id_cidade]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[uf] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[id_uf] = [Extent3].[id_uf]
        WHERE ( CAST( [Extent1].[id_cliente] AS nvarchar(max)) LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N''~'') OR ([Extent1].[razao_social] LIKE @p__linq__1 ESCAPE N''~'') OR ([Extent1].[fantasia] LIKE @p__linq__2 ESCAPE N''~'') OR ([Extent1].[cnpj] LIKE @p__linq__3 ESCAPE N''~'') OR ([Extent1].[endereco] LIKE @p__linq__4 ESCAPE N''~'') OR ([Extent1].[bairro] LIKE @p__linq__5 ESCAPE N''~'') OR ([Extent2].[cidade] LIKE @p__linq__6 ESCAPE N''~'') OR ([Extent3].[uf] LIKE @p__linq__7 ESCAPE N''~'') OR ([Extent1].[cep] LIKE @p__linq__8 ESCAPE N''~'') OR ([Extent1].[fone1] LIKE @p__linq__9 ESCAPE N''~'') OR ([Extent1].[fone2] LIKE @p__linq__10 ESCAPE N''~'') OR ([Extent1].[email_ordem] LIKE @p__linq__11 ESCAPE N''~'') OR ([Extent1].[referencia] LIKE @p__linq__12 ESCAPE N''~'')
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[razao_social] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__2 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__3 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__4 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__5 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__6 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__7 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__8 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__9 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__10 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__11 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__12 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'%conecta%',@p__linq__1=N'%conecta%',@p__linq__2=N'%conecta%',@p__linq__3=N'%conecta%',@p__linq__4=N'%conecta%',@p__linq__5=N'%conecta%',@p__linq__6=N'%conecta%',@p__linq__7=N'%conecta%',@p__linq__8=N'%conecta%',@p__linq__9=N'%conecta%',@p__linq__10=N'%conecta%',@p__linq__11=N'%conecta%',@p__linq__12=N'%conecta%'
```

Comment: The query and the linq do not match. Are you sure the captured query is from that linq statement? It could be from another statement in your code OR perhaps you are not running the compiled version of the code with this query.

Comment: Thank you Igor. You are right! I was running a LINQ query after the code and the result of it was being displayed and I had not delayed the code deviation for execution. Thank you for the tip.